# GWT: How can i get the updated values of textbox which i am making dynamically

Tags: java, gwt

I am creating a TextBox dynamically ,I get the values from server ,values could be 5,some times 10 etc , so No of textboxes i create will be different..

After all textboxes created .

There is an update button in page , When i click on this update button , Whatever changes user may have entered in any of the textBox,should Need to go to the server .. That I am not able to do ..

below is the code where i create the textBoxes

```
 public void fetchData(){
    public void onSuccess(ArrayList<Details> result) {
          for(int i =0;i<result.size();i++){


                name  = new TextBox();
                name.setText(result.get(i).getName());
                                    verticalPanel.add(name);
                                    namesList.add(name);
                                    }}
```

Suppose name value is at this time :  admin
Now user goees to the UI and change admin to  adminNew
then click update button

Here what i do on update Button

```
                public void Update(){

                     for(int i =0;i<namesList.size(); i++){
         String updatedNanme = namesList.get(i).getText());
    }
```

}

Now how will I get the updated name which user have changed from UI(i.e adminNew), in updatedName field.
Right now i am getting the old name(i.e admin) which i got from fetchData Method.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get textbox's value by calling getText(), not the "old value". I think there's a problem with your textbox list. maybe instantiate the textbox two times!
I suggest you debug your code, put a breakpoint on when textbox is instantiated and when the update occures. See if both are the same instance (for example if you're using eclipse watching a variable, id of the variable is shown in front of it. this is the object's id for VM. check if id of textbox that was instantiated is the same as id of textbox you are getting value from)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be possible that you override the content of text box with the user entry  ? Your update method will always set updatedNanme to the content of the last element from your namesList array.
And how do you access the updatedNanme string ? This string is only available in the for loop ?